# How can I change all subdomains to read different content from their respective subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I have my DNS configured to accept any subdomain (wildcard *), but I am having trouble feeding back the required content to the browsers.

I would like each subdomain to return the relative content, which resides in subdirectories of the same name within the `public_html` path of my server.

eg, `example.domain.com/picture.jpg` would actually request the file at `public_html/example/picture.jpg`

Currently I have tested the followed .htaccess code, but it is not functional:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         %1/$1 [L]
```

This code, and similar tests, can redirect based on the subdomain (%1) fine, but the request string ($1) seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could take a look at the mod_vhost_alias module :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+).domain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

I didn't test this one but I use similar rules for proxying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.local [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.local/%1/$1 [P]
```